# How to count total by current year of current month in mysql

Tags: mysql, count

I have bellow snippet table format.

Table name:- `wp_lead_count_freevendor`

```
id entryid start_date end_date   user_id count_set entry_date cancel_set_date
70 11392   2015-12-03 2015-12-03 3185            1 2015-12-03 2015-12-04
71 11393   2015-12-03 2015-12-03 3185            1 2015-12-03 2015-12-04
72 11394   2014-10-01 2014-10-01 3185            1 2014-10-01 2014-10-01
```

Here i want to calculate count total `count_set` column. of current month & year by `start_date` column `WHERE` `user_id`=3185.

suppose in `start_date` current year is 2015 & current month is 12:-

```
year   month   count total 
2015    12     2
```

For user id 3185 of this month of year `count_set` total =2

so any body will tell how do i fire the query to get `count_set` total for current year of current month for `user_id`=3185.

I have tried bellow query but its not working.

```
    $check_per_month=mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%Y') as 'year',
    DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%m') as 'month',
    COUNT(id) as 'total'
    FROM wp_lead_count_freevendor WHERE user_id=$wp_lead_count_user_id
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%Y%m')") OR DIE(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_per_month))
    {

    echo $sql_chk_current_month_count=$row['total'];

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to count using the where , year and month methods like this:

```
SELECT .... WHERE YEAR(start_date)=2015 AND MONTH(start_date)=12
```

Comment: i have created query but have some syntax error can you guide me to make it workable query:- $query = mysql_query("SELECT sum(count_set) AS 'meta_sum' FROM wp_lead_count WHERE user_id=$wp_lead_count_user_id AND DATE(end_date)='$wp_lead_count_end_date'") OR DIE(mysql_error());

Comment: How this '$wp_lead_count_end_date' looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
  SELECT YEAR(NOW()) as `year`,MONTH(NOW()) as `month', SUM(count_set) as `count_set`
  From  wp_lead_count_freevendor
     WHERE YEAR(start_date)=YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(start_date)=MONTH(NOW()) AND user_id=3185
        group by YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this query:**

SELECT YEAR(NOW()) as `year`,MONTH(NOW()) as `month', SUM(count_set) as` count_set`
From  wp_lead_count_freevendor
WHERE YEAR(start_date)=YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(start_date)=MONTH(NOW()) AND user_id=3185
group by YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())
you will get the answer else call this number :8124124555